# How can I ignore data from insert select join if data exists?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

I'm working with my code in C# and I have this query..

```
Insert into emp_names(emp_ln, emp_fn, emp_mi, emp_id)
  select ow.own_ln, ow.own_fn, ow.own_mi, emp_sequence.nextval
  from own_names ow 
    join businesses bn on bn.own_code = ow.own_code 
    join business_que bnque on bnque.own_code = ow.own_code
  where bn.mms = '33334' or bnque.bin = '33334';
```

The query is for insertion of data from one table `own_names` to `emp_names` where i join the  two table columns that has a value on `own_code` from table `own_names`. The query works on my code but my problem is when I tried to run the query again, it recreate the rows having different id since that is auto incremented. What I want is to ignore the data that exits on the `emp_names` table

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge into` instead of insert. You table should have also "real" business primary key, aside from emp_id. Use this one in merge `on` condition.